# Highcharts with reveal.js: Refresh chart with slide?

Tags: highcharts, reveal.js

I would like to include a Highchart graphic in a reveal.js presentation. The chart integrates fine, but the chart animation (e.g. growing of bar charts) plays while the "slide" is not visible yet.

How can I force an animation "refresh" when the slide changes?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to simply create the chart again when you want the animation to start.

I'm not an expert on Reveal.js, but it looks like you have an event when a slide is changed which you could use to redraw your chart to animate it:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    redrawChart();     
} );
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a big step forward for me. I guess I can just include that within script tags inside my HTML code. Will try.

Comment: Still stuck. Found the right position to put the code (according to https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/226#issuecomment-10261609 below the `Reveal.initialize` call), but it seems Highcharts doesn't know **what** to redraw (e.g. `chart1.redrawChart()`). With the way I construct my chart, I don't know what the name of my chart is:

`$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
...`

Comment: `chart.redraw()` is the correct method (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw).  To get your chart object use `Highcharts.charts[0]` where `0` represents the first chart you initialized.  Instead of redrawing your chart, you should just initialize it (`$('#container').highcharts...`) in the `slidechanged` event.

Comment: redrawChart() should be a function you write which draws the chart. it is not a highcharts call. Just put all your chart draw code in that one function and call it when the slide changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! By putting the chart code in the slideChange event, I was able to find an initial solution. However, I would like to use a switch statement based on the slide number, but I don't know how to address it. For charts on the second slide `if (event.currentSlide == 1) {` (or 2) doesn't seem to work, so my guess is I'm not referring to the index correctly.

Comment: It looks like event.currentSlide should be the way. Try logging event.currentSlide in the EventListener to see what values it has (e.g. alert or console.log).